# ngx-admin new module and components not running

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, ngx-admin

I am using Akveo/ngx-admin template for my project. I have created a new module inside the pages module and created some components inside my new module. In the pages module there are already some modules that were already there so i just created the new module followed the same approach as other modules did for defining the routes of a new module and its components inside it. The template code is in this github repo [akveo/ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin). So now after running my code i tried to access my new component but it just redirected me to `page not found` component.

Here is my code snippet for my new `classes-and-students-routing-module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: ClassesAndStudentsComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'upcoming-classes',
            component: UpcomingClassesComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'scheduleclass',
            component: ScheduleclassComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'pastclasses',
            component: PastclassesComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'instructorbidding',
            component: InstructorbiddingComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'keycodesales',
            component: KeycodesalesComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'studentsearch',
            component: StudentsearchComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'unscheduledstudents',
            component: UnscheduledstudentsComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'shipping',
            component: ShippingComponent
        }
    ]
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClassesAndStudentsRoutingModule {
}
```

pages-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: ECommerceComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'iot-dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'classes-and-students',
      loadChildren: () => import('./classes-and-students/classes-and-students.module')
        .then(m => m.ClassesandStudentsModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'layout',
      loadChildren: () => import('./layout/layout.module')
        .then(m => m.LayoutModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'forms',
      loadChildren: () => import('./forms/forms.module')
        .then(m => m.FormsModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'ui-features',
      loadChildren: () => import('./ui-features/ui-features.module')
        .then(m => m.UiFeaturesModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'modal-overlays',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modal-overlays/modal-overlays.module')
        .then(m => m.ModalOverlaysModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'extra-components',
      loadChildren: () => import('./extra-components/extra-components.module')
        .then(m => m.ExtraComponentsModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'maps',
      loadChildren: () => import('./maps/maps.module')
        .then(m => m.MapsModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'charts',
      loadChildren: () => import('./charts/charts.module')
        .then(m => m.ChartsModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'editors',
      loadChildren: () => import('./editors/editors.module')
        .then(m => m.EditorsModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'tables',
      loadChildren: () => import('./tables/tables.module')
        .then(m => m.TablesModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'miscellaneous',
      loadChildren: () => import('./miscellaneous/miscellaneous.module')
        .then(m => m.MiscellaneousModule),
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    },
  ],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

pages-menu.ts

```
import { NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';

export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [

  {
    title: 'Classes and Students',
    icon: 'layout-outline',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Upcoming Classes',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/upcoming-classes',
      },
      {
        title: 'Schedule a Class',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/scheduleclass',
      },
      {
        title: 'Past Classes',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/pastclasses',
      },
      {
        title: 'Instructor Bidding',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/instructorbidding',
      },
      {
        title: 'Keycode Sales',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/keycodesales',
      },
      {
        title: 'Student Search',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/studentsearch',
      },
      {
        title: 'Unscheduled Students',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/unscheduledstudents'
      },
      {
        title: 'Shipping',
        link: '/pages/classes-and-students/shipping'
      }
    ],
  }
}
];
```

classes-and-students.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  NbAccordionModule,
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbListModule,
  NbRouteTabsetModule,
  NbStepperModule,
  NbTabsetModule, NbUserModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';

import { NbIconModule, NbInputModule, NbTreeGridModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { UpcomingClassesComponent } from './upcoming-classes/upcoming-classes.component';
import { NewsService } from '../layout/news.service';
import { TablesRoutingModule, routedComponents } from '../tables/tables-routing.module';
import { ScheduleclassComponent } from './scheduleclass/scheduleclass.component';
import { TablesComponent } from '../tables/tables.component';
import { SmartTableComponent } from '../tables/smart-table/smart-table.component';
import { TreeGridComponent } from '../tables/tree-grid/tree-grid.component';
import { FsIconComponent } from '../tables/tree-grid/tree-grid.component';
import { ShippingComponent } from './shipping/shipping.component';
import { PastclassesComponent } from './pastclasses/pastclasses.component';
import { InstructorbiddingComponent } from './instructorbidding/instructorbidding.component';
import { KeycodesalesComponent } from './keycodesales/keycodesales.component';
import { StudentsearchComponent } from './studentsearch/studentsearch.component';
import { UnscheduledstudentsComponent } from './unscheduledstudents/unscheduledstudents.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ThemeModule,
        NbTabsetModule,
        NbRouteTabsetModule,
        NbStepperModule,
        NbCardModule,
        NbButtonModule,
        NbListModule,
        NbAccordionModule,
        NbUserModule,
        NbTreeGridModule,
        NbIconModule,
        NbInputModule,
        ThemeModule,
        TablesRoutingModule,
        Ng2SmartTableModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        // UpcomingClassesComponent,
        // ScheduleclassComponent,
        // TablesComponent,
        // SmartTableComponent,
        // TreeGridComponent,
        ...routedComponents,
        FsIconComponent,
        ShippingComponent,
        PastclassesComponent,
        InstructorbiddingComponent,
        KeycodesalesComponent,
        StudentsearchComponent,
        UnscheduledstudentsComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        NewsService,
    ],
})
export class ClassesandStudentsModule { }
```

unfortunately i could not create a stackblitz component for this problem because there is some kind of error while importing this project into stackblitz so please try to help me here in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't import `ClassesAndStudentsRoutingModule`.

It should be imported in `ClassesandStudentsModule`:

```ts
import { ClassesAndStudentsRoutingModule } from './classes-and-students-routing.module';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ClassesAndStudentsRoutingModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class ClassesandStudentsModule { }
```

Your `ClassesandStudentsModule` would look like this:

classes-and-students.module.ts

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  NbAccordionModule,
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbListModule,
  NbRouteTabsetModule,
  NbStepperModule,
  NbTabsetModule, NbUserModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';

import { NbIconModule, NbInputModule, NbTreeGridModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { UpcomingClassesComponent } from './upcoming-classes/upcoming-classes.component';
import { NewsService } from '../layout/news.service';
import { TablesRoutingModule, routedComponents } from '../tables/tables-routing.module';
import { ScheduleclassComponent } from './scheduleclass/scheduleclass.component';
import { TablesComponent } from '../tables/tables.component';
import { SmartTableComponent } from '../tables/smart-table/smart-table.component';
import { TreeGridComponent } from '../tables/tree-grid/tree-grid.component';
import { FsIconComponent } from '../tables/tree-grid/tree-grid.component';
import { ShippingComponent } from './shipping/shipping.component';
import { PastclassesComponent } from './pastclasses/pastclasses.component';
import { InstructorbiddingComponent } from './instructorbidding/instructorbidding.component';
import { KeycodesalesComponent } from './keycodesales/keycodesales.component';
import { StudentsearchComponent } from './studentsearch/studentsearch.component';
import { UnscheduledstudentsComponent } from './unscheduledstudents/unscheduledstudents.component';

import { ClassesAndStudentsRoutingModule } from './classes-and-students-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ThemeModule,
        NbTabsetModule,
        NbRouteTabsetModule,
        NbStepperModule,
        NbCardModule,
        NbButtonModule,
        NbListModule,
        NbAccordionModule,
        NbUserModule,
        NbTreeGridModule,
        NbIconModule,
        NbInputModule,
        ThemeModule,
        TablesRoutingModule,
        Ng2SmartTableModule,
        ClassesAndStudentsRoutingModule, // here
    ],
    declarations: [
        ClassesAndStudentsComponent, // Updated
        // You need to uncomment the other components below
        // UpcomingClassesComponent,
        // ScheduleclassComponent,
        // TablesComponent,
        // SmartTableComponent,
        // TreeGridComponent,
        ...routedComponents,
        FsIconComponent,
        ShippingComponent,
        PastclassesComponent,
        InstructorbiddingComponent,
        KeycodesalesComponent,
        StudentsearchComponent,
        UnscheduledstudentsComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        NewsService,
    ],
})
export class ClassesandStudentsModule { }
```

Comment: i am sorry that i didn't put this file here because i thought that file won't be necessary since i said in my explanation that i followed the same approach as other modules so i thought maybe everyone will get the idea that i have created all the necessary files. Anyways i am editing my question. Even though all the necessary modules are there and each and every single route is defined without any kind of error its quite difficult for me now to find out what is the problem that i am unable to route to my new module's components and i am stuck on this problem since yesterday :(

Comment: loved this answer :) but now i am seeing this error in the console.
`core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component ClassesAndStudentsComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component ClassesAndStudentsComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

Comment: in the already created components in template each routing file is declared like above in the module file but when i do it in my module i get error.

Comment: @ahsannissar Like error says, you have to declare `ClassesAndStudentsComponent` you want to route in the module. I've updated the post with that.

Comment: Thanks alot for saving me, dude. Bless youuuu :)